# Get a List count using the name of the List

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have 2 List(of String). Lets call them myList1 and myList2. Each of these list(of String) have items added and removed from them based on user actions. Elsewhere in the code I populate a string variable with the name of one of those 2 List(of String). Lets call it myString.

So lets say `myString = "myList2"`. How would I go about getting the count of the number of items in myList2 from only that string value? Would I have to use some kind of `DirectCast()` or `CType()` on myString?

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of options.

1:

```
Select Case myString
  Case "myList1"
    Return myList1.Count
  Case "myList2"
    Return myList2.Count
End Select
```

2:
Store your lists in a dictionary:

```
Dim myDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

myDictionary.Add("myList1", New List(Of String))
myDictionary.Add("myList2", New List(Of String))
...
Return myDictionary(myString).Count
```

AVOID reflection in this case.  Its unnessecary and will lead to terrible code.

Comment: I never would have thought to use a Dictionary. It worked beautiful. Thank you so much for a great solution.

Comment: @user1886834: If this answer solves your problem, don't forget to click the check mark to accept the answer and give Dan-o some Stack Overflow love :)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to do it that way without lots of reflection. It would be better to save a count variable:

```
Dim listCount = myList2.Count
```